# Dilation/erosion on 2D array of chars

Tags: c++, image-processing, mathematical-morphology, image-morphology

I am trying to figure out why my function for dilating an image doesn't produce the correct output.

My goal is to turn something like this:

```
.........
.........
....x....
.........
.........
```

into this:

```
.........
....x....
...xxx...
....x....
.........
```

for each cycle of dilation.

I haven't thought of it but I also need to to the reverse for the erosion.

This is what I've come up with so far (the program takes in input from the user in the command line using `argv`) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
//look up line by line parsing
using namespace std;
void replacee(vector<vector<char>> &vec, char oldd, char neww)
{
    for (vector<char> &v : vec) // reference to innver vector
    {
        replace(v.begin(), v.end(), oldd, neww); // standard library 
algorithm
    }
}
void dialationn(vector<vector<char>> & vec, char suspect)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++) {
                if (vec[i][j] == suspect) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                     vec[i-1][j] = suspect;
                    }
                    if (j > 0) {
                     vec[i][j-1] = suspect;
                    }
                    if (i + 1<vec.size()) {
                        vec[i+1][j] = suspect;
                    }
                    if (j + 1<vec[i].size()) {
                        vec[i][j+1] = suspect;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    fstream fin; char ch;
    string name (argv[1]); //File Name.
    vector<vector<char>> data;
    // 2D Vector.
    vector<char> temp;
    // Temporary vector to be pushed 
    // into vec, since its a vector of vectors.
    fin.open(name.c_str(),ios::in);
    // Assume name as an arbitrary file.
    string argument2 (argv[2]);
    string argument3 (argv[3]);
    string argument4 (argv[4]);
    while(fin)
    {
        ch = fin.get();
        if(ch!='\n') {
            temp.push_back(ch);
        }
        else 
        { 
            data.push_back(temp); 
            temp.clear(); 
        }
    }
    if (argument2 == "replace") {
        replacee(data, argument3[0], argument4[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++) {
                cout << data[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    } else if (argument2 == "dialate") {
        dialationn(data, argument3[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++) {
                cout << data[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    fin.close();
}
```

the `dialationn` function I've implemented so far uses a double for loop to cycle through the 2d array, and when it finds the character that is supposed to be dilated, it checks if a border is near by and sets the coordinate accordingly.

Comment: Can you add more details on what you mean by "won't work"?  And I see some typos where you're using the comparison `==` instead of the assignment `=`.

Comment: by wont work i mean it wont print in the commandline, also, ive fixed the == typo's

Comment: How about skipping over the command-line stuff and file reading, and just make a direct call to the function in question with hard-coded data?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i would do that if i could but it needs to be able to work with different arangements and sizes of files

Comment: Ever hear of "unit testing"?  Your function should work regardless of where the data comes from.  It would be much easier to have hard-coded data and call the function directly.  Even in your question, you have a diagram of hard-coded data, and you say your program doesn't work.  So test *that* data, not some random stuff from the command-line or file.  Once you see the data you posted work, *then* you introduce file reading and whatever other frills.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ill try it out and see if i can get any life out of it, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @xannax159 [Here is an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84ce353eb4569f5e).  No need for any file reading or command-line arguments.  The vector is set up exactly as in your question, and I made some call to one of the functions using whatever characters I'm testing with for the command-line argument.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ah, i see looks like i need to polish that dilation  function. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @xannax159 -- Take that as a lesson -- never waste time writing fancy input or output routines if you haven't tested and vetted the functions that are actually important in getting your program to work correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie lesson taken, this also helped me find a solution, i ended up setting the new characters not to x, but to i. since using my current function overlaps when doing the dilatation. Then a replace function at the end to turn it to normal! again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the input parsing issue discussed in the comments to the question, the dilation function proposed by OP doesn't work because it modifies the input image, rather than writing to a new output image. When modifying the input, the result of the dilation for subsequent pixels will be affected.

Correct would be:

```
void dialationn(vector<vector<char>> & vec, char suspect)
{
    vector<vector<char>> out(vec.size(), vector<char>(vec[0].size(), 0))
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++) {
            if (vec[i][j] == suspect) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    out[i-1][j] = suspect;
                }
                if (j > 0) {
                    out[i][j-1] = suspect;
                }
                if (i + 1<vec.size()) {
                    out[i+1][j] = suspect;
                }
                if (j + 1<vec[i].size()) {
                    out[i][j+1] = suspect;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    swap(out, vec);
}
```